# In dash, how do I use a callback to update a graph when a radio button is selected?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm new to dash and I'm having problems finding examples on using data frames within a callback. I created a weekly radio button and a monthly radio button.

When the monthly radio button is selected I would like the graph to pull data from `df_monthly` where each bar would be a monthly sum of pay. When the weekly radio button is checked I would like to see the graph populate each bar on a weekly basis which would be each row in the data frame since I get paid once a week.

I'm not certain where I'm going wrong but I keep receiving an error stating `TypeError: update_fig() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

The graph populates without data like the picture below. Thanks for any help on this matter.

[image]

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc 
import dash_html_components as html 
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect('paychecks.db')

df_ct = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM CheckTotal',conn)
df_earn = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Earnings', conn)
df_whold = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Withholdings', conn)

data_frames = [df_ct, df_earn, df_whold]
df_paystub = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Date'], how='outer'), data_frames)

def date_extraction(df):
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y')
    df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B')
    df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d')
    return df

date_extraction(df_paystub)

df_monthly = df_paystub.groupby(['Month']).sum()

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/amyoshino/pen/jzXypZ.css'})

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.RadioItems(
                        id='data-view',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Weekly', 'value': 'Weekly'},
                            {'label': 'Monthly', 'value': 'Monthly'},
                        ],
                        value='',
                        labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
                    ),
        ], className = 'two columns'),

        html.Div([    
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='year-dropdown',
                options=[
                        {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df_paystub['Year'].unique()
                ],
                placeholder="Select a year",
            ),
        ], className='five columns'),

        html.Div([    
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='month-dropdown',
                options=[
                  {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df_paystub['Month'].unique()
                ],
                placeholder="Select a month(s)",
                multi=True,
            ),
        ], className='five columns'),
    ], className  = 'row'),


    # HTML ROW CREATED IN DASH
    html.Div([
        # HTML COLUMN CREATED IN DASH
        html.Div([
            # PLOTLY BAR GRAPH        
            dcc.Graph(
                id='pay',
            )
        ], className  = 'six columns'),

        # HTML COLUMN CREATED IN DASH
        html.Div([
            # PLOTLY LINE GRAPH
            dcc.Graph(
                id='hours',
                figure={
                    'data': [
                        go.Scatter(
                            x = df_earn['Date'],
                            y = df_earn['RegHours'],
                            mode = 'lines',
                            name = 'Regular Hours',
                        ),
                        go.Scatter(
                            x = df_earn['Date'],
                            y = df_earn['OtHours'],
                            mode = 'lines',
                            name = 'Overtime Hours',
                        )
                    ]
                }
            )
        ], className='six columns')
    ], className='row')
], className='ten columns offset-by-one')

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('pay', 'figure'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('data-view', 'value')])

def update_fig():
    figure={
        'data': [
            go.Bar(
                x = df_monthly['Month'],
                y = df_monthly['CheckTotal'],
                name = 'Take Home Pay',
            ),
                go.Bar(
                x = df_monthly['Month'],
                y = df_monthly['EarnTotal'],
                name = 'Earnings',
            )
        ],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title = 'Take Home Pay vs. Earnings',
            barmode = 'group',
            yaxis = dict(title = 'Pay (U.S. Dollars)'),
            xaxis = dict(title = 'Date Paid')
        )
    }
    return figure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @prime90 and welcome to Dash.

In glancing at your callback signature it looks like the `update_fig()` function needs to take the `Input` you've given it (using `dash.dependencies.Input`).

The callback is sending this `Input` what changes in your app you've specified. So it's sending along the `value` of `#data-view` you've given to your function `update_fig()`, which doesn't currently accept any variables, causing the error message.

Just update your function signature and add a couple of boolean variables to rid yourself of the error and get the potential functionality:

```py
def update_fig(dataview_value):
    # define your weekly OR monthly dataframe 
    # you'll need to supply df_weekly similarly to df_monthly
    # though DO NOT modify these, see note below!
    df = df_weekly if dataview == 'weekly' else df_monthly
    dfkey = 'Week' if 'week' in df.columns else 'Month' # eh, worth a shot!
    figure={
        'data': [
            go.Bar(
                x = df[dfkey],
                y = df['CheckTotal'],
                name = 'Take Home Pay',
            ),
                go.Bar(
                x = df[dfkey],
                y = df['EarnTotal'],
                name = 'Earnings',
            )
        ],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title = 'Take Home Pay vs. Earnings',
            barmode = 'group',
            yaxis = dict(title = 'Pay (U.S. Dollars)'),
            xaxis = dict(title = 'Date Paid')
        )
    }
    return figure
```

As was written in the comments above, you'll need to do some type of prior manipulation to create a df_weekly, as you have with your current df_monthly.

In addition, the code snippet I wrote assumes the df column is named "Week" and "Month"--obviously update these as is necessary.

**Data manipulation in Dash:**

Ensure you read the [data sharing docs](https://dash.plot.ly/sharing-data-between-callbacks), as they highlight how **data should never be modified out of scope**.

I hope this helps :-)